# What changes for a complexified Clifford algebra?

Tags: clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

If you complexify a Clifford algebra, does it mean just using complex scalars instead of reals? Or do any of the algebraic rules change? I suppose $\langle M\rangle$ will extract the full complex scalar?

Comment: What is your definition of a Clifford Algebra? If you consider $\Bbb{R}^2$ with quadratic form $q(x,y) = x^2 + y^2,$ then you should try to convince yourself that this will produce a different Clifford Algebra when compared to $\Bbb{C}^2,$ with the same quadratic form.

Comment: @Chickenmancer I'm not sure what that means. I'm using a Clifford algebra where all vectors square to e^2=+1. I'm assuming all (complex) scalars commute with vectors. Which particular algebraic expression transformation becomes invalid if I forget that my scalars are complex numbers and not plain real numbers?

Comment: Could you be more specific. I don't know what you mean when you say "I'm using a Clifford algebra . . ." I see that you require that $e^2= 1,$ but were you handed that rule, or did you derive that rule?

Comment: I'm not really sure which part is ambiguous. To my knowledge the dimension and what the vectors square to, defines all that someone needs to know about the algebra. Like https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CliffordAlgebra.html with equations (1) and (2). For orthonormal basis vectors you can choose between +1,0,-1. I'm not going into more abstract definitions. And what vectors square to isn't important here. This is works for real vector space (the algebra is based on), but I wonder if there are differences when you make such an algebra on complex vector spaces.